# Eslint - Method syntax in ReactJS - arrow function

Tags: reactjs, methods, ecmascript-6, eslint

In a react component I have the following syntax

```
deletePerson = () => {
}
```

In Eslint I get an error over the first =

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token =
```

What is wrong with this syntax?

Comment: The syntax looks good, but is the eslint version you have compatible with es7?

Comment: @stevelacerda7 It doesn't look good in ES7 either.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Babel to transpile your ES6, you'll need to use the Class Properties Transform to get that syntax to work:  [transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)

Comment: The question was about eslint, not about babel.

Comment: Sure, but without knowing how the OP has eslint configured it's still worth pointing out a possible missing plugin. Many folks use tools like `babel-eslint` and may not know how it all fits together.